# Is it possible to open DJI GO from another iOS app?

Tags: dji-sdk

I'd like to offer a graceful way to complete aircraft binding by simply tapping a button in my app to automatically redirect the user to DJI GO. Is there a custom URL scheme to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following URL schemes to redirect to the DJI Go iOS apps:

**`djiVideoNew://`** for DJI Go 4

**`djiVideo://`** for DJI Go 3